# Matching end of line or another character

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to write a regex which can match "key = value" up until end of line or a symbol indicating that a comment beginns.

For example, let '#' indicate a comment and assume I have a file containing the following:

```
k1 = v1 
k2 = v2 # this is a comment
k3 = v3
```

Then I want my expression to match upon "k1 = v1", "k2 = v2" and "k3 = v3".

I have been able to match text with no comments using:

```
^(?'key'.+)\=(?'value'.+)
```

The problem is that I cannot figure out how to match up until '#' or '\n'

Comment: @Tushar That doesn't look for a comment or newline at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?:^|(?<=\n))(?'key'.+?)\=(?'value'.+?(?=#|\n|$))
```

You can use `lookarounds` to do your job. See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/eB8xU8/3

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is fine except for the last dot

```
^(?'key'.+)\=(?'value'[^#\n]+)
```

If you replace it with the negated character class [^#\n] it will work

Also if the key value pairs are in in the same file (as opposed to line by line) you should enable multiline mode which lets ^ match at every line beginning

in C# this becomes

```
var subjectString = @"k1 = v1 
k2 = v2 # this is a comment
k3 = v3";

Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"^(?'key'.+)\=(?'value'[^#\n]+)", RegexOptions.Multiline);
Match matchResult = regexObj.Match(subjectString);
while (matchResult.Success)
{
    Console.WriteLine(matchResult.Groups["key"].Value);
    Console.WriteLine(matchResult.Groups["value"].Value);
    matchResult = matchResult.NextMatch();
}
```